# What's the maximum speed that is still considered walking?

Tags: pokemon-go

What's the fastest speed I can move until Pokemon Go no longer considers me to be walking?

Answer (score 2):

According to [reddit](https://m.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4x8vc3/egg_hatching_speed_105_kmh_with_science?utm_source=mweb_redirect&compact=true),

the game draws a straight line between two points and compares it to a max of 175 metres.

[image]

Although the total distance is same, the game draws an imaginary line between the two points and logs that distance.
Pythagoras theorem states that c2 = a2 + b2. Therefore, 123.743 = (87.5 X 87.5) + (87.5 X 87.5). Which would be known as .12 km in your egg log, which means you can travel with 10.5 km/h per hour.

Comment: This does not answer the question if you do not explain it.

Comment: Well, then let me edit it

Comment: Click on the edit button and edit it.

Comment: Phew! And i know how to edit it.

Comment: @Frank Now is it good?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.  You state how distance is logged, but that has zero relevance on how fast you can move.

Comment: @Frank Just read the last line 

Comment: You have no source to back that up.  To me, you're pulling that out of thin air.  Everything before that supports it, but you're answering the wrong question.

Comment: @Frank Added the source

Comment: @DeMize I'm not trying to invalid your answer, but is reddit (and this specific reddit user and post) reliable enough to be considered as the correct answer? I know it seems like it but, without an official information, this might be wrong.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna if you define official information as information from niantic, it does not exist. empirical testing is the next best thing